# Serenity BDD Report is too heavy

Tags: java, report, serenity-bdd

I'm using serenity bdd. I have 600 tests. And the report weight is 2Gb. Is it normal? How can i decrease report weight?
Serenity versions i'm using:

```
<serenity.core.version>1.9.20</serenity.version>
<serenity.cucumber.version>1.9.8</serenity.cucumber.version>
<serenity.rest.assured.version>1.9.20</serenity.rest.assured.version>
```

Answer (score 0):

answered in https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-core/issues/2082 :

- use the latest version
- disable screenshots or only "on failure"